# How to abbreviate version control information in the mode line?

Tags: mode-line, version-control

**Q:** how can I abbreviate the version control information in the mode line?

Buffers visiting a file under version control display branch information in the mode line as `VCtype-branch`.  That's fine, but my mode line is already quite cluttered, so I'd like to abbreviate that information if possible.  I can always use short branch names, but I'm wondering if I can at least shorten the `VCtype` information (eg, `Git-mybranch` => `G-mybranch`).  How would I do this?

PS My understanding (which could be wrong) is that [`diminish`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiminishedModes) would not be relevant in this situation.

Comment: It's not worthy of an answer, but if you know exactly what you want and don't want in your modeline, writing your own `mode-line-format` might be a great option for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a piece of advice that shortens `Git` to `G`, while leaving mode line strings for other version control systems unchanged:

```el
(defun my-shorten-vc-mode-line (string)
  (cond
   ((string-prefix-p "Git" string)
    (concat "G" (substring string 3)))
   (t
    string)))

(advice-add 'vc-git-mode-line-string :filter-return 'my-shorten-vc-mode-line)
```

It uses the new advice facility introduced in Emacs 24.4.

---

On earlier Emacs versions, you need to use `defadvice` to define an `around` advice that modifies `ad-return-value`:

```el
(defadvice vc-git-mode-line-string (around shorten compile activate)
  (let ((string ad-do-it))
    (when (string-prefix-p "Git" string)
      (setq ad-return-value (concat "G" (substring string 3))))))
```